# How many codes can be made that differ on two positions

Tags: combinatorics

The maximal number of codes which differ in at least 2 positions seems to depended on chosen codes.

Example if a code is 2 characters long and consist only of 0,1,2 then there are 3 possible codes
**00, 11, 22**

For codes with a length of 3 there are 7 or 9 possible codes

- 7 code  (**001, 020, 111, 122, 200, 212, 221**)
- 9 codes (**001, 012, 020, 102, 110, 121, 200, 211, 222**)

if $l$ is the length of the code and $n$ is the number of different charters then

- all unique codes = $n ^ l$
- Codes which differ in at least 2 position <= $n ^ {(l-1)}$

In the above example the number of codes is 7 or 9 ($n = 3$ and $l = 3$),
and the maximum number of codes that can garanteed random be generated is 7

$g_{max} = 3^2-2 = 7$

**question:**

What is the maximal number of codes that can be garanteed at random generated which differ in 2 positions.

I think $g_{max}$ is something like

$g_{max} = n ^ {(l-1)} - ...$

Comment: Do you mean that any two codewords differ in *at least* two positions?  Also, what do you mean by the minimal number of codewords?  Why isn't that zero?  What requirements must be satisfied?

Comment: @saulspatz The answer is $q^{n-1}$ by the Singleton bound.

Comment: I update the question